# Canvas Colors broken?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

My canvas colors have completely broken after adding some code, and I have no idea why. It used to have a lot of colors, but it now only shows red and black. My current code is here:
https://gist.github.com/Ptolemy2002/1423a7ce6412130c4be7694178c983cd

My old code is here:
https://gist.github.com/Ptolemy2002/b36f0088fc8fed713ec88262aed2faf8

Comment: With no running example and way too much code to sift through your chances of getting a quick answer are low. Use the devTool (hit F12 in the browser) go to the source tab (debugger tab FireFox) open the js file (can be found on left panel) then in the source view, add a breakpoints and inspect the variables. You can also use the console tab and console.log(data) to output data to check if the values are correct. Through a process of elimination you will soon locate the problem. That is how we would solve the problem if there was a running example.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a simple naming error. I had accidentally named one function in my object the same thing as another function. The new declaration overrode the old one.

I had actually done this with 2 functions (stroke and fill).